# BigCommerce Webhooks Don't Work

Tags: bigcommerce

I am having a problem with BigCommerce web hooks. I have run an SSL check and our certificate is valid. BigCommerce responds with the correct list of web hooks, it's just that they don't send any posts for new orders. What else can I do to debug this?

Comment: Have you checked that is_active is set to true?

Comment: Good thought.  Yes, I did.  Here's the result of a GET:[{"id":12402882,"client_id":"3k42lsft3gfma6o426o8yye3a4q7pso","store_hash":"<store Hash>","scope":"store/order/created","destination":"https://api.progressivepii.com","headers":null,"is_active":true,"created_at":1499106428,"updated_at":1499106428}]

Comment: We only have the one web hook now and we still don't get anything when a new order is placed.  Any ideas?  BigCommerce, are you listening?

Comment: I would recommend using the order/updated webhook instead. As for why you aren't receiving a webhook at all, it seems like an issue with the code itself. It would be helpful to see how you are listening and supposed to be responding to the webhook.

Comment: I saw that suggestion elsewhere, as well, and I added a webhook for 'updated' as well.  We tried several test orders, both new ones and updates, and we still receive nothing.  We have monitors on our server, logging all incoming connections, and nothing has been received from BigCommerce.